# Как сделать юнит тесты для игры на js?

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, jasmine, mocha

Добрый день.

Есть браузерная игра на js, весь код в одном файле, файл подключается к html.
Возник вопрос о том, как сделать юнит тесты для игры.
Смотрел примеры на mocha и jasmine, но там тестируются самые простые функции которые возвращают конкретное значение и в тестах это возвращаемое значение сравнивается с ожидаемым. В моем случае, функции в коде не возвращают ничего, одна задает картинки, другая меняет координаты игрока, другая рисует и т.п.
Пример такой функции:

```
function checkReadyState() {
if (game.gameOverAudio.readyState === 4 && game.backgroundAudio.readyState === 4) {
    window.clearInterval(game.checkAudio);
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
    game.start();
}}
```

Эта функция не возвращает ничего, и как здесь можно понять, прошла она тест или нет? Или для каждой функции добавить какое-нибудь особое возвращаемое значение, которое будет говорить о том, что функция отработала успешно?

Как тестировать такой код? И в каком файле это нужно делать, если весь код в одном файле? В тестировании я новичок, поэтому, полагаюсь на ваши советы. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Возник вопрос о том, как сделать юнит тесты для игры.

В вашем случае, никак.

По определению, [модульный (он же юнит) тест](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) проверяет маленький **изолированный** фрагмент кода - *модуль*. Судя по примеру кода из вопроса, ни о какой модульности приложения не идет речь. Совсем.

Если очень-очень хочется сделать именно **модульные тесты**, начните с выделения модулей и изоляции зависимостей модулей друг от друга. Вопрос о том, как именно выделять модули и разрывать зависимости требует отдельного обсуждения и должен ставиться на примере конкретного кода.

Если же стоит задача **протестировать** приложение, а времени на подготовку кода к модульному тестированию нет, то можно начать с [*функционального тестирования*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_testing). При использовании этого подхода, вы проверяете корректность работы не отдельного изолированного модуля, а более крупного куска приложения. В вашем случае - это может быть все приложение целиком. (В последнем случае я бы говорил о End-to-End тестировании, но это уже вопрос терминологии.)

При этом, нужно понимать: функциональное тестирование, не замена модульному, а дополнение. БОльшую часть кодовой базы должны покрывать именно модульные тесты, а функциональные тесты должны проверять *взаимодействие* между модулями.

Если говорить об инструментах для функционального тестирования, то тут может быть очень много вариантов. Я бы начал с [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) (или чего-то подобного).

А вот и пример функционального теста с использованием CasperJS

```
casper.test.begin('Game start', 5, function suite(test) {
    casper.start('http://www.example.com/', function() {
        test.assertTitle('Game title');
        test.assertExists('form#user-info');
        this.fill('form#user-info', {
            username: 'Foo'
        }, true);
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertTitle('Game started for Foo!');
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Во-первых, это странно, что в функции с названием `checkReadyState()`  запускается игра. Не логичнее было бы возвразать `true/false` и потом исходя из этого заупускать игру? Тогда вам просто нужно написать тест для функции на проверку `true/false` значения. Если уж пишете в [функциональном стиле](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), так пишите чистые функции.